# Output Chinese characters on watchOS app

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

I'm trying to build a language-learning app for the Apple Watch. I'm looking for some guidance on how to output traditional Chinese characters as strings. Are there any classes that handle foreign languages, or is it a font I need to select? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

San Francisco Compact (the native font) **supports Chinese characters natively**. You can access it by selecting the System font in Interface Builder or by using `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:)` in code.

Comment: Thanks, are there other fonts I choose other than San Fran?